# How to best run a database background action?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a user workflow where at a specific time a webservice is called, and the results are presented to the user.

According to the search request and the queried results, I want to perform some database updates and statistic logging.

As the workflow pauses while the webservice is requested, I thought about creating some kind of background thread that performs these database actions, while the user can already continue the workflow without having to wait for database actions to complete.

Do you think this is a good practice? How could I create such onetime running background threads?

Comment: It is a good practice to do this.  I'd read some documentation about threads and `ExecutorService` classes.  Specifically the `Future` and `Callable` sections which can be used to return results to the caller.

Comment: Use a job scheduler service like [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to create the tasks to run at a specific time and day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to run in the background, then an `Executor` service is a good solution.

If you need to ensure that queued requests survive events like a server restart, then you need a persistent queue like a [JMS Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service).  There are some nice, free open source JMS implementations that serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If service call teakes little time (say 1 or 2 seconds) then it is a waste of time to develop such feature.

If it takes significant amount of time you should do this in background.